# Как пересобрать словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Есть словарь

```
a ={A:set([aa,bb]), B:set([dd,ee])}
```

Как его можно быстро привести к виду:

```
a ={A:[aa,bb], B:[dd,ee]}
```

Первое что приходит в голову - распаковывать через for и обрабатывать каждый элемент из items:

```
for f ,ff in a.items():
    rr = list(ff)
    list_params[f] = rr
```

Может есть более простые способы?

Comment: `{k: list(v) for k,v in a.items()}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо отличающихся способов нету, если хотите короче можно написать так:

```
list_params = dict((key, list(value)) for key, value in a.items())
```

Comment: Тогда уж: `list_params = {k : list(v) for k, v in a.items()}` :)

Comment: @gil9red хотите сказать что будет особая разница?)

Comment: Для тех, кто `хотите короче можно написать так` :)